# can one identify firefox browser instances leaking from selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

We run a lot of scrapers and we seem to end up with a lot of extra processes hanging around. We *do* make sure we quit our browsers at the end of a run, but obviously something may be happening when a scrape crashes or is interrupted.

When I run a 'ps -auxwwwww', I see (on a Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS system):

```
root      875464  875463  5 13:45 ?        00:11:15 /usr/bin/python3 foo1.py
root      909167  909166  2 16:30 ?        00:00:52 /usr/bin/python3 foo2.py
root      911702  911701  0 16:31 ?        00:00:13 /usr/bin/python3 foo3.py
root      915807  915805  1 16:35 ?        00:00:22 /usr/bin/python3 foo4.py
root      917485  917484  0 16:36 ?        00:00:13 /usr/bin/python3 foo5.py
root      919214  919213  8 16:37 ?        00:02:01 /usr/bin/python3 foo6.py
root      921380  921379 15 16:40 ?        00:03:06 /usr/bin/python3 foo7.py
root      926541  926540  0 16:48 ?        00:00:04 /usr/bin/python3 foo8.py
```

I see this and I think, we have 8 scrapes running. That seems ok.

But then I also see this:

```
root      766621       1 12 10:25 ?        00:50:29 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox --marionette --headless --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage --ignore-certificate-errors user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36 -no-remote -profile /tmp/rust_mozprofileMLcj81
root      766774  766621 26 10:25 ?        01:45:31 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 1 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 1 -prefMapSize 233311 -jsInit 278680 -parentBuildID 20211028161635 -appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 766621 true tab
root      766813  766621  1 10:25 ?        00:04:52 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 85 -prefMapSize 233311 -jsInit 278680 -parentBuildID 20211028161635 -appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 766621 true tab
root      766926  766621  0 10:25 ?        00:00:01 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 3 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 7696 -prefMapSize 233311 -jsInit 278680 -parentBuildID 20211028161635 -appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 766621 true tab
```

and this:

```
root      916001  915970 21 16:35 ?        00:05:19 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox --marionette -headless start-maximized disable-infobars --disable-extensions --disable-application-cache --disable-gpu --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage --ignore-certificate-errors user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36 -no-remote -profile /tmp/rust_mozprofileYc8Rmk
root      916120  916001  6 16:35 ?        00:01:38 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 1 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 1 -prefMapSize 233359 -jsInit 278680 -parentBuildID 20211028161635 -appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 916001 true tab
root      916139  916001  1 16:35 ?        00:00:17 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 85 -prefMapSize 233359 -jsInit 278680 -parentBuildID 20211028161635 -appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 916001 true tab
root      916210  916001  0 16:35 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 3 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 149 -prefMapSize 233359 -jsInit 278680 -parentBuildID 20211028161635 -appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 916001 true tab
root      916216  916001  0 16:35 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 4 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 149 -prefMapSize 233359 -jsInit 278680 -parentBuildID 20211028161635 -appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 916001 true tab
root      916251  916001  0 16:36 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 5 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 1074 -prefMapSize 233359 -jsInit 278680 -parentBuildID 20211028161635 -appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 916001 true tab
root      916432  916001  0 16:36 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 6 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 7899 -prefMapSize 233359 -jsInit 278680 -parentBuildID 20211028161635 -appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 916001 true tab      392663       1  1 Apr05 ?        2-04:16:25 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox --marionette -headless start-maximized disable-infobars --disable-extensions --disable-application-cache --disable-gpu --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage --ignore-certificate-errors user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36 -no-remote -profile /tmp/rust_mozprofileEHvISm
root      392826  392663  1 Apr05 ?        2-04:14:08 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 85 -prefMapSize 233359 -jsInit 278680 -parentBuildID 20211028161635 -appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 392663 true tab
root      392877  392663  0 Apr05 ?        04:01:26 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 3 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 85 -prefMapSize 233359 -jsInit 278680 -parentBuildID 20211028161635 -appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 392663 true tab
root      392881  392663  0 Apr05 ?        04:00:54 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 4 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 85 -prefMapSize 233359 -jsInit 278680 -parentBuildID 20211028161635 -appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 392663 true tab
root      392927  392663  0 Apr05 ?        04:10:12 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 5 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 1010 -prefMapSize 233359 -jsInit 278680 -parentBuildID 20211028161635 -appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 392663 true tab
root      393116  392663  0 Apr05 ?        00:29:37 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 6 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 7899 -prefMapSize 233359 -jsInit 278680 -parentBuildID 20211028161635 -appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 392663 true tab
```

So I see these families of processes, where this a parent process and then a bunch of sub-processes that have that as their parent.

But I do not see 8 families of processes. I see 20 sets of these.

At first, I thought that if the parent of the parent was process # 1, then that must mean there is a problem there. But there are only 2 process families whose root is at process 1.

So, what the heck?

I have 8 scrapes running and I should have hundreds of processes running? Doing what?

I could reboot the machine but that seems lame. And I suppose that I could have our scripts write their process numbers out into some data store and see if those processes stick around. But it seems that I should be able to see, from the running system, if these processes are connected, yes?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue, but I know now more about the thing:

> Multiprocess Firefox, also known as "Electrolysis" (often shorted as "e10s"), offers a major improvement to your browsing experience by separating Web content and Firefox UI processes. This means when a web page is consuming a large part of your computer’s processing power, your tabs, buttons and menus won’t lock up.

The cause that you have a lot of **firefox -contentproc** can be that you do kill the main firefox process, BUT unfortunately that doesn't kills the children processes.

Those are hanging around, and that's why you see them.

We were needed to implement custom logic to kill "by hand" the subprocesses.

For more information about those processes see https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis.